# ASP.NET MVC view word doc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ms-word

I have to make a ASP.NET MVC web page wherein a word doc has to be viewed. The idea is that the page allows user to view documents stored in a local directory.

I tried to google it, but all I could find useful is that word doc converted to .htm format can be viewed inside an iframe, but I have to make use of the .doc file.

I need to apply the same technique to view ppt and visio diagrams.

Can anyone suggest any ideas.

Thanks.

Comment: You only specify `.doc` so I am assuming you aren't dealing with `.docx` or `pptx` files?

Comment: well, you can always iframe the document itself however client browser rules will determine if they're displayed inline or downloaded. If you want to force them to view it inline you'll have to convert the document to a form native to the browser, such as html, flash viewer or images.

Comment: @ahsteele : yes I am limiting myself to doc and ppt files only

Comment: @BuildStarted : the page needs to open in chrome and firefox

Comment: Correct, which means the client will either need a plugin to view the doc/ppt files or you have to convert them into a generic format such as those listed. Google Docs Viewer is probably the easiest path for you http://docs.google.com/viewer you can embed their stuff use the `embedded=true` to embed it in your webpage

Comment: Do you want to just send a file for download/open to the user - or actually convert it to a viewable format and show it in a browser window.. just want to clarify that.

Comment: @Adam: I need to convert file to a viewable format and show it in browser.

Comment: @BuildStarted: Is there any other way except Google viewer?